# switch / create desktop C# opening form inside

Tags: c#, multithreading, forms, class

hi there I have been working on this program for a long time my goal is to have a lock system that will switch between desktops with a login form on the 2nd screen to allow you to login but I have run into a problem that I can not get the login from2 too close so the second desktop can be destroyed I have to manually close it I have tried invoking the close and hide I have tried to destroy the process but I will not close but it will not close. 
if I use the method .ShowDialog to open the form but if I you use .show . it will close the form but then any parts of the work will show as blank windows

form1 this is the main form that will process the request

```
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            // Create the thread object. This does not start the thread.
            Worker workerObject = new Worker();
            Thread workerThread = new Thread(workerObject.DoWork);

            workerThread.Start();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
            workerObject.RequestStop();

        }

    }


    public partial class Worker
    {
            static Desctop mDesktop = new Desctop();

        // This method will be called when the thread is started. 
        public  void DoWork()
        {

            mDesktop.CreateNewDesktop("Mayshotspot");
            using (Form2 frm = new Form2())
            {

                frm.ShowDialog();
                while (!_shouldStop) { }
                frm.Close(); // this will not close the form 
            }

            mDesktop.DestroyDesktop();
            mDesktop.destroyProces();




        }

        public void RequestStop()
        {
            _shouldStop = true;
        }
        // Volatile is used as hint to the compiler that this data 
        // member will be accessed by multiple threads. 
        private volatile bool _shouldStop;



    }




}
```

Screen switch class

```
        static string DesktopName = "Mayshotspot";
        ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
        public  bool NeedBootStrapping()
        {
            return (GetDesktopName() == DesktopName);
        }
        public static string GetDesktopName()
        {
            int DLength = 0, DHandle = GetThreadDesktop(GetCurrentThreadId());
            StringBuilder DName = new StringBuilder();
            GetUserObjectInformation(DHandle, UOI_NAME, DName, 0, ref DLength);
            if (DLength != 0) GetUserObjectInformation(DHandle, UOI_NAME, DName, DLength, ref DLength);
            return (DName.ToString());
        }

        public void CreateNewDesktop(string DesktopName)
        {
            GetThreadDesktop(GetCurrentThreadId());
            OpenInputDesktop(0, false, DESKTOP_SWITCHDESKTOP);
            int DesktopHandle = CreateDesktop(DesktopName, "", 0, 0, GENERIC_ALL, 0);
            SetThreadDesktop(DesktopHandle);
            SwitchDesktop(DesktopHandle);
        }
        public void DestroyDesktop()
        {
            CreateNewDesktop("Default");
        }

        public Process StartProcess(string Path)
        {
            PROCESS_INFORMATION PI = new PROCESS_INFORMATION();
            STARTUPINFO SI = new STARTUPINFO();
            SI.cb = Marshal.SizeOf(SI);
            SI.lpDesktop = DesktopName;
            bool Result = CreateProcess(null, Path, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, true, NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS, IntPtr.Zero, null, ref SI, ref PI);
            if (Result)
            {
                // WaitForSingleObject(PI.hProcess, INFINITE);
                // CloseHandle(PI.hProcess);
                //CloseHandle(PI.hThread);
                list.Add(PI.dwProcessId);
                return Process.GetProcessById(PI.dwProcessId);
            }
            else
            {
                DestroyDesktop();
                return null;
            }
        }

        public void SetProcessPriorityHigh()
        {
            SetThreadPriority(GetCurrentThread(), THREAD_BASE_PRIORITY_MAX);
            SetPriorityClass(GetCurrentProcess(), REALTIME_PRIORITY_CLASS);
        }

        public void ExitProces(int uExitCode)
        {

           // ExitProcess(uExitCode);
            Process.GetProcessById(uExitCode).Kill();
        }
        public void destroyProces()
        {
            Process thisProc = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
            foreach (int p in list)
            {
                try
                {
                    Process.GetProcessById(p).Kill();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                }
            }
        }

        public void exitProces()
        {
            ExitProcess(0);
        }
```

form 2 - the login screen that will appear the the desktop switch  is left with default at the moment till I can find why it will not close

Comment: Please see [this one](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for a possible solution.

Comment: HI there I have broken it down I can ever get it to start but not put the from on the second desktop or I will get the frame but it will not close itself

Comment: Break it down more :-) E.g. remove all those `using`s, remove the `namespace`, remove the blank lines, do you really nead the `extern` declarations?, etc. Your readers have to scroll horizontally _and_ vertically, which usually makes the question rather unattractive IMHO.

Comment: Sorry I hope this is a better read for you I have removed all the basic and removed some functions